# Auto-merge is causing all vertices to snap to same distant vertex

Tags: vertices, snapping

I almost always edit with snapping to vertex and auto-merge on, but today when I started a project, no matter which vertex I move, and no matter where I move them, they all snap to the exact same vertex which is nowhere near them. I even scaled up significantly to make sure it wasn't a large threshold issue. If I move the vertex that they all are being snapped to, it just snaps to the nearest vertex no matter where I move it as well.

First screenshot shows the vertex I have selected and the arrow shows where I attempt to move this selected vertex...
[image: This is the vertex I have selected and the spot I WANT to move and merge to.]

And without fail, they always get merged to here...
[image: All vertex movements result in merging here.]

Comment: As I tried on 2.75 eveything works as expected. As a workaround you may turn off Auto snapping and use `W` > *Remove doubles* after snapping by hand. Also you may upload your blend for further investigation.

Comment: I'm on 2.75. If I start a new scene it works fine. This one doesn't. It was just a super simple SVG I imported and converted to a mesh.

Comment: Does it work if importing it once more in another blend? Otherwise you can recreate your mesh with roughly modeling first and applying Shrinkwrap modifier after that; this will give opportunity to stop messing with corrupted mesh to the newly created similar one.

Comment: I tried appending the mesh to a new blend file, and interestingly, this behavior still only affects this particular mesh, while other meshes in the same file behave appropriately.